# like option in a website using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have a problem like this. I am creating a website using codeigniter. In it, users can ask questions and "like" them. All questions should be shown in the website by descending Order by the amount of like. If the first questions has 20 like and the second one has 18 and then, a person likes the second question ,then it has 19 likes it should stay in same place if it got 21 likes it should come to the top. 
How can i do this? 
I search internet so many times but i couldn't able to find out something suitable.

This is my question table.

[image: This is my question table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view you have something like that i guess:

```
<input type="button" class="likeAction" data-questid="<?=$question->id?>" value="Like">
```

In jquery, when a like button is cliked, read the value of the data(questid) and you should start an ajax query to the likeQuestion method.

I don't know your code so I just write as i do it...

In your controller :

```
public function likeQuestion($quest_id){
    $json = (object) []; //init an object, easier to use with json
    $json->result = "error";

    $res = $this->question_model->like($quest_id);
    if($res){
        $json->result = "success";
        //read the number of like of the question 
        $json->num_like = $this->question_model->countLikeNumber($quest_id);

    }

    header("Content-type:application/json");
    echo json_encode($json);

}
```

In your model :

```
public function like($quest_id){

    $this->db->set('likes', 'likes+1', FALSE); //the false is important here
    $this->db->where('id', $quest_id);
    $this->db->update('question');

}

 public function countLikeNumber($quest_id){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('question');
    $this->db->where("id", $quest_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->num_rows();
 }
```

Comment: Well, you have many option.

Fisrt, in PHP/html only : 
Create one function in your model to increment the "likes" of your question table.
Your "like" button is a link which redirect to a method (for exemple... `likeQuestion()` ) of your controller, with 1 parameters, the question ID.

This method call your model, question_model i guess, and increase the value of "likes".

Then, redirect to your previous page.

Comment: I have created a similar method like  this.I want to avoid that from full page refreshing.I just want to refresh just that particular part

Comment: then to not refresh it, you have to change a little the code and use ajax query instead of html link.

The logic is quite similar. Your Ajax shoud call the likeQuestion method, which, instead of redirect the page, should return a JSON result like `{"result : "success", "likes_num" : 19}`. And then, in javascript, you overwrite the current number of like by the number returned by the JSON

Comment: `countLikeNumber($quest_id);` should i create a method like this in model

Comment: I think so, it's not that hard to do. I update my code if you want.

Comment: Thank you.can you help me to do, when a like button is cliked, read the value of the data(questid) and you should start an ajax query to the likeQuestion method too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163872/discussion-between-tharindu-sandaruwan-and-eiji).

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that you want to send your [adding like] request via ajax, and then ordering your list according the number of likes for each question, and I'll cover basically your front-end code reading the comments, so:

Your view should be like this:

```
<ul class="questions">
    <li id="question_item_<?= $id ?>">
        ...
        <span id="likes_<?= $id ?>"><?= $likesNum ?></span>
        <button class="likeBtn" data-id="<?= $id ?>" >Like</button>
    </li>
    <li id="question_item_<?= $id ?>">
        ...
        <span id="likes_<?= $id ?>"><?= $likesNum ?></span>
        <button class="likeBtn" data-id="<?= $id ?>" >Like</button>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Your Ajax Call:

```
$('.likeBtn').click(function(){
    var $clicked = $(this),
        questionID = $clicked.data('id'),
        likesNum = $('li#question_item_' + questionID).find('span').text;
    $.ajax({
       url: 'PATH_TO_YOUR_CONTROLLER_METHOD_addingLike',
       data: {'question_id': questionID},
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(returnedData){
           if(returnedData.status === 'success'){
               $('li#question_item_' + questionID).find('span').text(parseInt(likesNum ) + 1);
               reorderQuestions(returnedData.ids);
           }
       },
       error: function(error){
           console.log(error.resposeText);
       }
    });
});

/* Reordering your list at the front-end base,
 * preventing server resources highly consumptions 
 */
function reorderQuestions(ids){
   var newUL = $('<ul class="questions">');
   $each(ids, function(index, id){
        newUL.append($('li#question_item_' + id));
   });
   $('ul.questions')replaceWith(newUL);
}
```

Your Controller Should behave like this:

```
public function addingLike($question_id){
    # Increasing the number of like for question holding the specific id,
    # Fetching all your questions ids ordered by the number of its likes
    # Return a json object ['status': success, 'ids': [array_of_ids_ordered_by_likes]]
}
```

Comment: Of course you can filter your second fetch by sending more parameter to your `addingLike` method. Like sending all questions' ids in that specific view while clicking like button.